# "Declaration does not declare anything" and "expected unqualified-id"

Tags: c++, xcode

compiling this code in Visual Studio is totally fine.

```
bool check(void);

bool check(void) {
return true;
}
```

But in XCode(Apple LLVM) I get warning on declaration

```
Declaration does not declare anything
```

and error on definition

```
Parse Error: expected unqualified-id
```

What is going on here? How can I fix this?

Comment: What is that function supposed to be doing? It doesn't even return a bool (or anything for that matter)... What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC on Mac there exists a macro "check" that will interfere with your function name. Try mycheck.

Comment: Yes, I already pointed out that. Thanks. That is pretty stupid :)